# Upgrade magento 2 theme

Tags: magento2, theme, magento-upgrade, porto-theme

I have upgraded Magento with the latest version (i.e 2.4.4).
I would like to start upgrading the theme now (i.e Porto theme).

Version "2.2.1" is currently installed & version "4.0.2" is the latest, how can I upgrade the theme to the latest version & ensure custom changes not affected?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Any fastest way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to work with a custom theme is to create your child's theme with the custom theme as the parent. In this case, you would create a new child theme with Porto 2.2.1 as the parent. If you know which Porto template, code, or layout files you have customized you can copy these to your child theme to preserve your changes.

With your child theme working, you can upgrade the parent theme to 4.0.2 without losing your customizations. You can then compare any files you have changed with the update to check for any updates/fixes in the theme you might need to implement yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer !

Comment: Any fastest way to do it ?

Comment: I can see two themes in app/design/frontend/Smartwave
One is porto & another is porto_rtl.
Can you please tell me how can I upgrade in this scenario?